# Updating Array on Functional Component ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am a newbie to ReactJS, I wanted to make API calls within a function component. I wanted to fill [TreeBeard](https://github.com/storybookjs/react-treebeard) component, with the list I take from an API call.

I can see the data updating on my console, but for some reason the data from TreeBeard doesnt.

Here's a bit of my code:

```
export default function Users() {

const [userAccounts, setUserAccounts] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/accounts`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers:{
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "x-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
        }
      }
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => {
        setUserAccounts(response);
        console.log("Accounts")
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  },[UserAccounts]);


  const data = {
    name: 'Accounts',
    toggled: true,
    children: userAccounts
  };
  const [data, setData] = useState(data);

  const onToggle = (node, toggled) => {
    if (cursor) {
        cursor.active = false;
    }
    node.active = true;
    if (node.children) {
        node.toggled = toggled;
    }
    setCursor(node);
    setData(Object.assign({}, data))
    console.log("Toggled")

return (
          <GridItem xs={4} sm={12} md={7}>
           <Treebeard data={data} onToggle={onToggle}/>
          </GridItem>
         
);
}
```

I think the `const data`- `children` parameter is where I should assign the list taken, according to TreeBear samples, but when I do it, it still looks empty even though on the logs `userAccounts` contains an array of records.Is there any step I forgot to take? or did I mess up the handling?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNSeU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be.

When the code reaches this section.

```
const data = {
    name: 'Accounts',
    toggled: true,
    children: userAccounts // <---- this is [], data has not loaded yet.
  };
```

data.children is [].

`userAccounts` gets updated after the data has been fetched.
But nothing updates the `data.children` afterwards.

You could try to use this code snipped in the `.then(response => {` code section to see the data gets updated.

```
setData( {
  name: 'Accounts',
  toggled: true,
  children: response
})
```

Some more code shuffling might be needed to make work as intended.
But hope this gets you started with using the loaded data.